# How to scrape multiple elements using Scrapy and Xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors, tuples

I am trying to scrape a website. I need to get the name of a product and its reference. The html from which I am scraping is:
`<li> <a href="wensite?area=areacode" class="dropdown-element" data-code="areacode" style="cursor: pointer;">Name of the item</a>`

The spider needs to yield a tuple with the product name and its area code. Currently I am able to scrape the item name using the following Xpath selector '//li/a[@href]/text()' but I don't know how to yield the areacode at the same time.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

try using this xpath expression to scrape the area code

```
//li/a/@data-code
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For anyone with a similar problem i would like to point ouy that this Xpath expression yields the area code, but i in my case i was looking for a expression that yields both the area code and the product name. Despite that i would like to thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

To get both the area code and item name at the same time, try this expression:

```
//li/a[@href]/(@data-code,text())/string()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. 
Scrapy is not yelding a tuple, in fact is not yielding anything at all, i dont know if there is a problem with my spider or with the Xpath itself.

Anyway thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.

Comment: @M.Cerv - You're welcome and sorry it didn't work. One thing you may want to try is process the xml using lxml (if available) and this xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will give you a list in the format of `[Name, AreaCode]`

`response.css('dropdown-element ::text, dropdown-element ::attr(data-code)').getall()`

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this to `yield` a tuple:

```
for el in response.css("li"):
    yield (el.css("a::text").extract_first(), el.css("a::attr(data-code)").extract_first()),
```